# Hide/Show Google Maps markers based on category with checkbox's

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, checkbox, hide, show

I've searched thoroughly and spent two full working days on this, so far I can't find a scenario that matches mine specifically. I'm learning on the fly here, ok here goes...

I'm using the google maps api v3. I have 12 pub locations (markers) on the map. Above the map I have checkbox's defining categories, 1 pub may fit under numerous categories. I want to show only the pub within the particular category on a checkbox click and hide the remaining.

I've tried numerous solutions to no avail, i've stripped it back to the bare minimum for new eyes. Thanks for your time.

Live link: http://xii.com.au/pubmap

Javascript:

```
var infowindow = null;
    $(document).ready(function () { initialize();  });
    function initialize() {
    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.854000, 144.900432);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            minZoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 20,
            center: centerMap,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles:[{
                featureType:"poi",
                elementType:"labels",
                stylers:[{
                visibility:"off" /* Hide POI */
                }]
            }]
        }
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), myOptions);
            setMarkers(map, sites);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
       var center = map.getCenter();
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
           map.setCenter(center); 
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "loading..."
            });
    }

    var sites = [
          ['Customs House Hotel', -37.86314,144.904012, 9, '<a class="orange" href="#">Customs House Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_25.png" /></p>'],
          ['Juntions Beer Hall & Wine Bar', -37.843199,144.883992, 1, '<a class="orange" href="#">Juntions Beer Hall & Wine Bar</a><p>Newport</p><p><img src="img/stars_45.png" /></p>'],
          ['Morning Star Hotel', -37.86426,144.899121, 11, '<a class="orange" href="#">Morning Star Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_35.png" /></p>'],
          ['Pirates Tavern', -37.862818,144.907381, 8, '<a class="orange" href="#">Pirates Tavern</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_3.png" /></p>'],
          ['Prince Albert Hotel', -37.853337,144.896165, 2, '<a class="orange" href="#">Prince Albert Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_4.png" /></p>'],
          ['Rifle Club Hotel', -37.858244,144.888843, 4, '<a class="orange" href="#">Rifle Club Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_25.png" /></p>'],
          ['Rose of Australia Hotel', -37.85892,144.899105, 6, '<a class="orange" href="#">Rose of Australia Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_3.png" /></p>'],
          ['Stags Head Hotel', -37.8661,144.906562, 12, '<a class="orange" href="#">Stags Head Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_35.png" /></p>'],
          ['Steam Packet Hotel', -37.863519,144.90268, 10, '<a class="orange" href="#">Steam Packet Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_4.png" /></p>'],
          ['Victoria Inn', -37.85676,144.897547, 3, '<a class="orange" href="#">Victoria Inn</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_25.png" /></p>'],
          ['Williamstown RSL', -37.858342,144.894213, 5, '<a class="orange" href="#">Williamstown RSL</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_3.png" /></p>'],
          ['Yacht Club Hotel', -37.862191,144.902608, 7, '<a class="orange" href="#">Yacht Club Hotel</a><p>Williamstown</p><p><img src="img/stars_3.png" /></p>']
    ];

    function setMarkers(map, markers) {

      var image = {
            url: 'img/pin.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(33, 41),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 41),      
          };

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var sites = markers[i];
            var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: siteLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: sites[0],
                zIndex: sites[3],
                html: sites[4],
            });     

      var contentString = "";
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);

            });
        }       
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

HTML

```
<h1>Pubs</h1>
        <div class="subhead">
        <div class="tags">
            <ul>
            <li class="current"><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="all"> All &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="craft-beer"> Craft Beer &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="beer-garden"> Beer Garden &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="night-club"> Night Club &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="quiz-night"> Quiz Night &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="steak-night"> Steak Night &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="parma-night"> Parma Night &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="tab"> TAB &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="live-sport"> Live Sport &nbsp;</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="live-music"> Live Music</label></li>
        </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<div id="googlemap"></div>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined (index):17`

Comment: I don't see any of your categories associated with the locations.

Comment: I wasn't sure how I 'attach' the categories to particular markers. I've used the checkbox's filtering divs previously:

<div class="all beer-garden craft-beer"></div>

Comment: @geocodezip Did you include the Google Maps API?

Comment: Did you try running his code as written?

Comment: I did in fact, and have a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cincodenada/u6zX9/4/) of my modifications to it (see my answer).  Also, the [live link](http://xii.com.au/pubmap) provided works fine.

Comment: To illustrate: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cincodenada/zgTvE/1/) is a fiddle with the code as-is pasted in.  Literally the only changes I made are the necessary includes (jQuery, GMaps API and OP's css) and making the image URL on the marker absolute (to OP's website) so jsFiddle could get to it.

Comment: Go to his [site](http://xii.com.au/pubmap), click on a check box. Chrome gives me an error here: `marker[i].setVisible(false);`.  Don't see that line in your fiddle, you must have fixed it, or changed something.

Comment: Ah, well I was working off of the code in the question. I'm sure the errors on the live site are why OP posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cincodenada/u6zX9/4) that demonstrates how to set this up, but overview: store references to your markers in an array, and then when the checkboxes are clicked, run through your list of pubs and show or hide the markers depending on whether they match.

The critical bit is in the for loop where you create your arrays.  Here's a modified version that will set things up:

```
markerobj = [];
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var sites = markers[i];
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
    markerobj[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: sites[0],
        zIndex: sites[3],
        html: sites[4],
    });

    var contentString = "";
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerobj[i], "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);

    });
}
```

And then the handler to filter them when the checkboxes are changed:

```
$('.tags').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    filter = $(this).val();
    for (i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
        //Test to see if the entry matches, for now we'll just make it random to illustrate the concept
        //e.g. if(filter in sites[i].attrs)
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            markerobj[i].setVisible(true);
        } else {
            markerobj[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

That code will just randomly pick about half of the markers to show, just to demonstrate that it is indeed hiding and showing things.  You'll have to put some actual logic in there in place of the Math.random(), probably checking the filter against something in the entry for that marker.  The important bit is that now you have a list of the Marker objects that are mapped to the same indexes as your sites, so you can alter the Markers on the map based on information in the sites array.

In order to filter things, somewhere (probably in the sites array) you're going to have to list which attributes the pub fulfills that you can check against.  Supporting filtering by multiple attributes will require some additional checking (when any checkbox is changed, you'll need to pull the values of all the checkboxes and check each item against all of them), but this example should get you back on track.

*Other notes:* you'll have to declare `markerobj` as a global variable like the `sites` array, so you can get to it from the callback.  I would recommend using the value of the checkbox to store what it's filtering for, rather than the id - my code above assumes that the value of the checkbox is the filter.

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a legend. I'll have a crack at what you've suggested.

Comment: Glad I could help :) If it answered your question, make sure to mark the answer as accepted (it'll help your future answers as well).

Comment: Thanks, Previously I wasn't able to change the visibility to any of the markers, this is a huge help. I was wondering how/where I would add the 'filters' within the array of pubs (sites)?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, just somewhere you can get at it.  Another element in the array, although I would recommend changing the list of sites to a list of JSON objects, it'll make things a lot easier to maintain and read.

Comment: Dude, most of that has gone over my head. But I really appreciate your time anyway. I'll give you that tick!

I'm new to stackflow, are you available for paid work if I was to need your help further?

Thanks again.

Comment: Depends - if you want me to build things *for* you, I don't really do freelance at the moment, but if you want some more guidance/help, if you catch me in [an SO chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) I'd be glad to answer some questions if I'm not busy.  You can filter by user to see if I'm around.

Comment: Ahh, you don't have enough rep to chat yet.  Feel free to comment here, I suppose, or post another question and link me to it.

Comment: No worries bud, thanks again for your help thus far. Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to work as you're just showing and hiding the marker based on the index rather than the slug of a category.

Comment: @StevenJones which is why I said "That code will just randomly pick about half of the markers to show, just to demonstrate that it is indeed hiding and showing things. You'll have to put some actual logic in there in place of the Math.random(), probably checking the filter against something in the entry for that marker." OP didn't have any categories to sort by in their example data.